# Firefox download already cached file

Tags: firefox, caching, download, offline

For MS IE, I can dig out a already downloaded file from the browser cache, with this WIN32 API

```
DownloadFile = URLDownloadToFile(0&, sSourceUrl, sLocalFile, 0, 0) = ERROR_SUCCESS
```

Is there a simple way for Firefox?

How does Firefox store the link between the original URL and the cache filename?

places.sqlite? which tables and columns?

Comment: First, please accept some answers, this it how it works here! Second, I do not understand what you want to achieve, is the above code snippet javaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call [`nsICacheService.createSession()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsICacheService#createSession%28%29), then [`nsICacheSession.openCacheEntry()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsICacheSession#openCacheEntry%28%29) on the result. Basically, it's the same code as in [How to get images from cache using a XPCOM Component in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785455/how-to-get-images-from-cache-using-a-xpcom-component-in-firefox/4807502#4807502) but `clientID` should be `"http"` rather than `"image"` (you want to look at the HTTP browsing cache rather than the image cache).

At least that's how you do it from inside Firefox. I suspect that you want to read the cache from an independent application - well, good luck replicating Firefox code. http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/cache/nsDiskCacheMap.cpp should be a good starting point.